# Twitter Bootstrap - doesn't it break every good modern web-design principle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), since I was fascinated by all those responsive, well designed super-duper user-friendly stuff.
I've been quite disappointed in seeing that everything is just anti-good-principles!
I mean, did I get it wrong or you necessarly have to wrap everything you want to style into a `div` with an appropriate class? I can already see two broken principles: not using `div`s for everything and strongly mixing content with styling.

I'd appreciate any correction to what I said (e.g. is it possible to give a `header` tag a class of `row` and still benefit from Bootstrap design?).

### Edit

When I say "strongly mixing content with styling", I mean that you should not set which element is a column or how much space it takes by giving it a class: you should do that in the CSS stylesheet! Also, Bootstrap kind of forces you to overuse `div`s, which are pretty against accessibility.

Comment: I think this were better asked on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or maybe even [ux](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Twitter is pretty famous for doing everything wrong...

Comment: @merv I'm sorry, in fact I was not sure where to post this. I'm sorry then!

Comment: @cimmanon good to hear that, I was worried that I was the only one to think that since I read tons of articles on how Bootstrap is the right hand of God :).

Comment: It is a bit of a compromise. Think of TBS as a tool. If you need a screwdriver, don't use a hammer. Using TBS will save dev time, yet decrease semantics and increase bloat. If time is not an issue, by all means you should roll your own. Or use something a little lighter like: http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider myself experienced enough to tell if it's an anti-pattern or not, but to your second question, yes, you can place the .row and .span classes on any element, they are not constrained, see the source at:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L597
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L577

Comment: Ok, at least this is a relief! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in, the only usable compromise I ended up with is using the Less version of Bootstrap, instead of the pure CSS one.
That way, instead of adding a class of `span*` to a column, you include the `makeColumn(*)` mixin in the column style (in your Less stylesheet).

Honestly, after some more digging in, I just moved to SASS + Foundation and I'm seeing this thing from a whole new perspective... When coming to Less + Bootstrap I'm quite sure some wise old grey-bearded folk would say: **run, you fools!**